# Validation for Phone Number in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation

```
       <asp:TextBox ID="txt_PhNo" CssClass="txt_box" runat="server" />
       <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator5" ControlToValidate="txt_PhNo" runat="server" ValidationGroup="ORG"
CssClass="Error" Text="*Organisation Name is a required field."></asp:RequiredFieldValidator
```

How to add validation for phone number so that it allows + () and space, If I validate with numbers then + () and space are not allowed how to do that. Thanks

Comment: Checkout: [A comprehensive regex for phone number validation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/123559/a-comprehensive-regex-for-phone-number-validation).

Answer (score 3):

Investigate the [RegularExpressionValidator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eahwtc9e.aspx), perhaps in conjunction with [A comprehensive regex for phone number validation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/123559/20048)